# compile oracle form using powershell script

Tags: powershell, oracleforms

I have many oracle forms in one folder and I want to compile those forms through `frmcmp` command in powershell script.

I have written a powershell script which is following

```
 $module="module="   
    get-childitem "C:\forms\fortest" -recurse | 
        where { $_.extension -eq ".fmb" } | 
        foreach {
            C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\BIN\frmcmp $module $_.FullName userid=xyz/xyz@xyz Output_File=C:\forms\11\common\fmx\$_.BaseName+'.fmx'
        }
```

but this one is not working. i am new in powershell.

but when I try to compile a single form through command prompt its working like following.

```
frmcmp module=C:\forms\src\xyz.fmb userid=xyz/xyz@xyz Output_File=C:\forms\11\common\fmx\xyz.fmx
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? Error message? No results? Something completely different?

Comment: its not working means:- No results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use variables inside a string in PowerShell you have different options. To start with, you will always need to use `"` as opposed to `'` to wrap the string, if you want variables in your string.

```
$myVariable = "MyPropertyValue"
Write-Host "The variable has the value $MyVariable"
```

The above code would yield the output:

```
The variable has the value MyPropertyValue
```

If you want to use a property of a variable (or any expression) and insert it into the string, you need to wrap it in the string with `$(expression goes here)`, e.g.

```
$MyVariable = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ MyPropertyName = 'MyPropertyValue' }

# The following will fail getting the property since it will only consider 
# the variable name as code, not the dot or the property name. It will 
# therefore ToString the object and append the literal string .MyPropertyName
Write-Host "Failed property value retrieval: $MyVariable.MyPropertyName"

# This will succeed, since it's wrapped as code.
Write-Host "Successful property value retrieval: $($MyVariable.MyPropertyName)"

# You can have any code in those wrappers, for example math.
Write-Host "Maths calculating: 3 * 27 = $( 3 * 27 )"
```

The above code would yield the following output:

```
Failed property value retrieval: @{MyPropertyName=MyPropertyValue}.MyPropertyName
Successful property value retrieval: MyPropertyValue
Maths calculating: 3 * 27 = 81
```

I generally try to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet when I start processes in PowerShell, since it gives me the possibility of additional control over the process started. This means that you could use something similar to the following.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\forms\fortest" -Filter "*.fmb" -recurse | Foreach {
    $FormPath = $_.FullName
    $ResultingFileName = $_.BaseName
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\BIN\frmcmp.exe" -ArgumentList "module=$FormPath", "userid=xyz/xyz@xyz", "Output_File=C:\forms\11\common\fmx\$ResultingFileName.fmx"
}
```

You could also add the `-Wait` parameter to the Start-Process command, if you want to wait with compilation of the next item until the current compilation has completed.